# What happens if one uses a credit card to enter the MRT in Singapore, and then uses another credit card under the same name to exit?

Tags: trains, payment-cards, singapore

I have two Visa credit cards under my name. What happens if I use one to enter the MRT, and another one to exit?

E.g., am I going to get charged twice? Will I have to pay some extra fee? Will I get charged for the longest possible distance when exiting?

Comment: It is rather easy to put one card away safely and keep the other one near at hand, so the situation does not become a problem. And always take the card you use away from other ways you can pay for your ride.

Comment: @Willeke not that easy for me, and can be other issues eg forgetting to use the proper card when entering and trying to fix it by using the correct card when exiting. Which clearly is a bad idea according to [MJeffryes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/28009/mjeffryes)'s answer.

Comment: @Willeke Another reason that also happened to me (in addition to forgetting the card and also not using the proper card) was that the card I used to enter the MRT got rejected to exit, and the MRT customer service told me to use another card to exit. So I ended up facing this issues 3 times in 2 days, which made me start to wonder what to expect. Sounds like I'll have to jump at least 6 times to be even with the system without having to do the paperwork.

Comment: Why would you jump a turnstile? I get you want to square your account, but doing the paperwork won't wind up in a Singapore jail or deported. I feel like your willingness to be socially functional is oddly compromised.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica some jumpers were able to be reasonably well accepted by the society https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUN1r.jpg

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I am labelled socially dysfunctional in Singapore on appearance alone. I've visited Singapore a number of times. There are (or were) spot-a-terrorist signs which list telltale indicators of how bad-guys look or behave. I matched about half the list (and my wife agreed :-) ). Nobod ever turned me in.

Comment: I would advise if you are going to do any turnstile jumping to do it in a different country. Not Singapore. This is why most locals use a prepaid transit card rather than their credit/debit card. Even though the flexibility to be able to tap in with any card is great.

Comment: To be clear, the reason I think a prepaid transit card reduces the risk is because it is less likely to have a problem when you try to tap out like Franck describes. Which leads to a choice between jumping, being overcharged, or doing paperwork.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, you should never use an other card to exit and customer service should not have told you so, as they know that would mess up the payments. If told so again claim not to have an other card that works. Jumping the turnstiles is still not the way to get it sorted.

Answer (score 13):

You will note the signs around the MRT warning against 'card clash', which is exactly the situation you're describing.

You will be charged for two incomplete journeys. [This is a flat fee of S$2.20](https://www.simplygo.com.sg/faqs?tab=tabs-1131)

You will need to make a claim to be refunded [using this form](https://simplygo.transitlink.com.sg:8443/FrmCEPAS_SubmitClaims.aspx?source=directweb).

Also note, as a foreign card holder, you will be charged a daily fee of S$0.60 on any day you use your card. You may prefer to get an EZLink card if you will be using public transport a lot.

Comment: Thanks! "You will note the signs around the MRT warning against 'card clash', which is exactly the situation you're describing." I didn't see these signs yet, I'll pay more attention.

Comment: Isn't "card clash" rather about presenting multiple cards at the same time (e.g. by presenting your wallet which contains multiple cards)?

Comment: @jcaron yes, it's more warning against accidentally doing what the question describes. I think this demonstrates that you shouldn't do it on purpose.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you're not aware, you can also download the SimplyGo app and register your bank cards. This will let you check if you have had any incomplete journeys recorded.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks, I wasn't aware, great to know!